# IIS 6 Allow anonymous access by default

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-6

I have automated builds that will create IIS websites for me using FinalBuilder scripts. The problem is that in FinalBuilder there is no option to set 'allow anonymous access' to true on creation of the website, so I am forced to go into IIS manager and change this manually.

In an attempt to automate this procedure, I wrote a script that would update the IIS Metabase.xml. This works but because IIS changes are cached, the newly created website won't exist in Metabase.xml until it is updated from the cache. I've also attempted to modify the IIS Mbschema.xml to have all websites enable this option by default, but that was to no avail.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to force IIS to write the changes from the cache into the Metabase.xml, this way the new configurations will be available for editing. This is done using the command -

```
%systemroot%\system32\IIsCnfg.vbs /save
```